# How to write result of a program into a .csv file

Tags: r

I have written a R script for binning on the specific parameters of several .csv files in the same folder. I used the *smbinning* package. When I execute the script, it produces detailed results. I do not need all of them. I want to take a specific part of the results and write into a .csv file automatically. Can someone tell me how can I do this? My R script, details results, and wanted parts of result is as follows

My R script is as follows:

```
library(smbinning)　    
files <- list.files(pattern = "0.csv")     
cutpoint <- rep(0,length(files))    
for(i in 1:length(files)){    
   data <- read.csv(files[i],header=T)    
   df.train <- data.frame(data)    
   df.train_amp <-rbind(df.train)    
   cutpoint[i] <- smbinning(df=df.train_amp, y="cvflg",x="dwell")    
 }    
result <- cbind(files,cutpoint)
write.csv(result,"result_dwell.csv")
```

[image: Part of details result that I want to write into csv file.]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `View(result)` to see if the variable contains exactly what your require. Else there is something wrong in your logic.
There is function `sink` in R which writes the output of a program to a file.
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sink.html